# Como faço para exibir o botão FloatingActionButton?

Tags: java, android

Poderia me ajudar? Eu estou tentando fazer com que o botão FloatingActionButton aparecer na minha tela mas ele nao quer aparecer não sei mais o que faço...estou a um tempão tentando resolver esse problema mas eu não consigo resolver :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="br.com.gruporecursos.noamobile.AlertaFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lstAlerta"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:divider="#ECECEC"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        />



    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Em vez de `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"` use `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"`. Diga-me depois se o problema era esse.

Comment: Como está a usar o FloatingActionButton dentro de um LinearLayout e tem uma ListView por cima dele, tem de atribuir `android:layout_weight="1"` à ListView para que esta não "empurre" o FloatingActionButton para fora da tela. Pode usar um CoordinatorLayout como o Ack Lay explica na sua resposta, no entanto, num layout simples como este, o `android:layout_weight="1"` resolve o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize no seu layout a classe [**`CoordinatorLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)<sup>(*public class*)</sup>, para que você possa usar ancoragem `"bottom|end"` no seu [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html).

O `CoordinatorLayout` fornece uma camada adicional de controle sobre os eventos de toque entre suas *Views* filhas. Isso é utilizado por muitos componentes da biblioteca de suporte.

O `CoordinatorLayout` também fornece às suas *Views* os atributos `layout_anchor` e `layout_anchorGravity`, que podem ser utilizados para colocar alguma View "flutuando" relativamente a outra. Por exemplo o `FloatingActionButton` ancorado no canto inferior direito. Veja como deve ficar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstAlerta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#ECECEC"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```